# Saving dictionary to csv python

Tags: python

Hi When I try and save a dictionary to a csv using the following code:

```
with open(file, 'wb') as f:  # Just use 'w' mode in 3.x
    w = csv.DictWriter(f, my_dictionary.keys())
    w.writeheader()
    w.writerow(my_dictionary)
```

I get this error message

```
TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'
```

Is there a fix for this?

Comment: On which line are you encountering the error?

Comment: Open in `w` mode, not `wb` mode. The old bug for blank lines between rows in Windows is now fixed in Python 3 by adding `newline=''` instead of opening in `wb` mode.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You opened the file in binary mode hence the b you need to just get rid of that and put w and I think it should work. When a file is opened in binary mode it means that all the data read from a file is returned as bytes not of type 'str'. Thus if you wanted to keep the b there you would need to use bytes for everything else

Comment: No problem Happy to help :)

Answer (score 1):

I think this is not the best practice.
If your goal is only to get the dictionary in csv, then you can store the dictionary line by line with keys and values separated in the way you prefer,

```
with open('/home/sebastiano/Desktop/test.txt', 'w+') as f: 
         for k, v in d.items(): 
             f.write('{}, {}'.format(k, v))
```

Otherwise, you should use the library pickle, so you will be able to reload exactly as same object.

Comment: Using the DictWriter from the csv module is better practice than doing it this way. What if the strings in the dictionary contain commas? You wouldn't write a valid, or at least correct, CSV file from this